# sharepoint workflow with visual studio 2013 problem reference Microsoft.activities

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, workflow

I'm trying to deploy my workflow but I'm getting this error :

Erreur  4   XC1020 : une erreur de build s'est produite dans la tâche XAML MSBuild : 'XC1014 : impossible de résoudre l'assembly 'Microsoft.Activities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Ajoutez une référence à cet assembly dans le projet généré.'    c:\users\spadmin\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test7\test7\wf7\Workflow.xaml    test7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. for developers who have the same problem, I replaced Microsoft.activities Version 2.1.0 with version 1.0.0 in the reference section